# Monitor ZIP File Extraction Python

Tags: python, zip, monitor, progress, extract

I need to unzip a .ZIP archive. I already know how to unzip it, but it is  a huge file and takes some time to extract. How would I print the percentage complete for the extraction? I would like something like this:

```
Extracting File
1% Complete
2% Complete
etc, etc
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

here an example that you can start with, it's not optimized:

```
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip')

uncompress_size = sum((file.file_size for file in zf.infolist()))

extracted_size = 0

for file in zf.infolist():
    extracted_size += file.file_size
    print "%s %%" % (extracted_size * 100/uncompress_size)
    zf.extract(file)
```

to make it more beautiful do this when printing:

```
 print "%s %%\r" % (extracted_size * 100/uncompress_size),
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just monitor the progress of each file being extracted with [`tqdm()`](https://tqdm.github.io/):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from tqdm import tqdm

# Open your .zip file
with ZipFile(file=path) as zip_file:

    # Loop over each file
    for file in tqdm(iterable=zip_file.namelist(), total=len(zip_file.namelist())):

        # Extract each file to another directory
        # If you want to extract to current working directory, don't specify path
        zip_file.extract(member=file, path=directory)
```

Answer (score 4):

In python 2.6 ZipFile object has a [open](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) method which can open a named file in zip as a file object, you can sue that to read data in chunks

```
import zipfile
import os

def read_in_chunks(zf, name):
    chunk_size= 4096
    f = zf.open(name)
    data_list = []
    total_read = 0
    while 1:
        data = f.read(chunk_size)
        total_read += len(data)
        print "read",total_read
        if not data:
            break
        data_list.append(data)

    return "".join(data_list)

zip_file_path = r"C:\Users\anurag\Projects\untitled-3.zip"
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, "r")
for name in zf.namelist():
    data = read_in_chunks(zf, name)
```

Edit: To get the total size you can do something like this

```
total_size = sum((file.file_size for file in zf.infolist()))
```

So now you can print the total progress and progress per file, e.g. suppose you have only 1 big file in zip, other methods(e.g. just counting file sizes and extract) will not give any progress at all.

Comment: This code works great! Thanks. Do oyu know how I would get the total size of the uncompressed zip? That way I can print _Read xxxx of xxxxx_

Answer (score 0):

[`ZipFile.getinfolist()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) will generate a number of `ZipInfo` objects from the contents of the zip file. From there you can either total up the number of bytes of all the files in the archive and then count up how many you've extracted thus far, or you can go by the number of files total.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can track the progress of extracting a single file. The [zipfile extract function](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) has no callback for progress.