# Show extracting a .zip file progress Python Tkinter ProgressBar

Tags: python, tkinter, zip, progress-bar, ttk

I am working on a program that extracts a zip file which I have that part worked out. But I want to add a progress bar to show the progress of the extraction process. I already have a progress bar but it does not show the progress of the extraction. I would like it to start from point 0 and reach point 100 which would be the end when the extraction is done. But instead it just keeps repeating going from point 0 to point 100 until the extraction is done. How can I do this?

Code:

```
from threading import Thread
from Tkinter import *
import zipfile
import ttk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.pack()

        self.create_widgets()
        Thread(target=self.startExtr).start()

        def create_widgets(self):
            self.pBar = ttk.Progressbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode="determinate")
            self.pBar.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        def startExtr(self):
            self.pBar.start()

            with zipfile.ZipFile('Kerbal Space Program.zip', "r") as z:
                z.extractall("")


           self.pBar.stop()

root = Tk()
root.title("Test")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The progress bar needs a way to know how far through the unzipping it is. In the code above, you don't have a way for it to know.

Comment: @IronManMark20 Can you provide a example on how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After finding the answers not very helpful unfortunately :(. But I have managed to find a example that was very helpful and did exactly what I wanted! It got the percentage of the extraction :). Here is a link to where I found it: [Monitor ZIP File Extraction Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006970/monitor-zip-file-extraction-python)

Here is my new code:

```
from threading import Thread
from Tkinter import *
import zipfile
import time
import ttk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.pack()

        self.create_widgets()
        Thread(target=self.unzip).start()

   def create_widgets(self):
       self.pBar = ttk.Progressbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode="determinate", maximum=100, value=0)
       self.pBar.pack(side=BOTTOM)


   def unzip(self):
       zf = zipfile.ZipFile('Name of the zip file')

       uncompress_size = sum((file.file_size for file in zf.infolist()))

       extracted_size = 0

       for file in zf.infolist():
           extracted_size += file.file_size
           percentage = extracted_size * 100/uncompress_size
           self.pBar["value"] = percentage
           zf.extract(file)

  root = Tk()
  root.title("Test")

  app = Application(root)

  root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>`Zipfile` doesn't seem to include a built in way to read progress ([accodering to the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html)), so you might consider starting another thread and have your script check every little bit how many files are extracted in the new directory. This won't work for progress with one big file, but you would need to use a new library to get that functionality.</s>

I take that back. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341584/extract-zipfile-using-python-display-progress-percentage) for zip files.

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667865/python-tarfile-progress-output) for tar files.

Comment: I have already looked at those examples and unfortunately I did not find them helpful :(. But I have managed to find me something that was even more useful! It game the percentage of the extraction process like I was wanting! Here is a link to it but thanks anyways :)